# Remove xml attribute + subelement based on button click created with Tkinter interface

Tags: python, xml, function, xpath, tkinter

I have an issue in python, maybe some expert can help.

I've an XML file, I parse it, and extract some "tag" with Xpath, then I create a Tkinter interface to where buttons are created for each attribute found (This is done). Now what I want to do and where I'm stuck is that onclick of any button (number depends of the attribute found), the attribute is chosen in the XML will delete in an other node (which has the same name) is deleted + all element beside.

Better than workd this is my code :

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml


y = 0
' '
Tk().withdraw() 
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file


#Getting attribute to be delete in the xml
def getValues(tree, category):
    parent = tree.find("./body/hierarchy[@name='%s']" % category)
    return [child.get('name') for child in parent]
tree = xml.parse(filename)
val = getValues(tree, 'MainHierarchy')

==> here is the function which is not working
def delete():

def callback():


    if tree.findall("./body/objects/object/ORIGIN[@value='%s']" %   btn_dict[nodeval]): 
    root.remove("./body/objects/object/")
==>  Here is the function to be created which will delete the tag selected + all sub element beside which can be click and give the user choise to save the new file and select the new name<==


root = Tk()
#Creation of button with the dictionary 
btn_dict = {}
col = 0 
for nodeval in val:
    btn_dict[nodeval] = Button(root, text=nodeval , command=delete) 
    btn_dict[nodeval].grid(row=0, column=col, pady=10)
    col += 1 
# run the GUI event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Example my xml is:

```
<body>
  <object>
        <objects id="123" instanceof="screw">
            <origin = "M015" />
            <weight = "100/>
            ...
        <objects id="45" instanceof="nut">  
            <origin = "4512" />
            <size = "72" />
            ...
        <objects id="66" instanceof="nut">  
            <origin = "M015" /> 
            ...


  <hierarchy>
      <session name= "M015" />
      <session name= "4512" />
```

The tool will create two button one for "M015" one for "4512", if i click on button "M015" the macro should find  in all object. In this case id "123" should be deleted with all sub element and same for id "66".

I hope it was clear, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What part of the problem are you struggling with? Do you know how to remove elements from an xml document? Do you know how to call functions from buttons? What do you need help with?

Comment: Hello Bryan, i do not know how to call function from button and also to remove element i'm not really sure

Comment: I think it's nearly done, but i cannot save a new document or see the modification